# How can I identify this Bianchi bike model?

Tags: identify-this-bike

[image: Bianchi Bike - What Model?]

I bought this bike 2nd hand and I would like to find out more information about it, but cannot find it in the Bianchi catalogues. Might someone be able to give me some guidance?

Answer (score 8):

It's one of the cheaper tig-welded steel Bianchis from the 1990s with the cheapest Mirage or Xenon Campagnolo groupset. I have a similar model hanging up on some hooks here.

They are nice to ride and look great, yours is in fab condition.

It isn't one of the Bianchis that will make a collector's heart bleed. If you were buying this bike from new, you'd be buying into the name and the heritage without spending a fortune, and getting a good bike too, but it's the bottom model of the road range, or close to it.

Comment: Thank you JoeK!

Comment: May I ask: I am moving and am thinking of selling it. What could I ask for it?

Comment: I can't answer that. You can either decide what the minimum amount you'd part with it for would be or put it on ebay with a 99p start price and let the market find the true value. You may not get much over £100 for this spec with any other name, or maybe you'll get three times that. @Rebecca10002

Comment: @Rebecca10002  Nice bike !   I was estimating late 80s or early 90s based on the quill stem, and the unpopular triple chainring.  The frame pump is an interesting choice, harkening back to an older previous owner.  Would make a great first road bike for anyone that fits the frame size.  Consider family, or keep it as a Just In Case.

Answer (score 2):

Not all frames have the model name on the bike, but many do. In this case, Racing Comp (the decal just below your saddle) appears to have been a model name that Bianchi used in the late 1990s. Here is a [1998 Racing Comp](https://www.lfgss.com/conversations/239843/) with a different groupset and paint scheme.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks!